# Error with Set range data table

Tags: vba, excel

I have an error when I run this macro and even with the debug procedure, I'm unable to find what is wrong

```
Sub Update(brand)

Dim c As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Integer

brand = brand & "_Param"

For Each tbl In Worksheets("Assumptions").ListObjects
        Set Rng = Range(tbl.name)
        For Each c In Rng
            If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
                Worksheets(brand).Range(c.Address).Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next
Next tbl


End Sub
```

the issue comme from `Set Rng = Range(tbl.name)`
I got the error message: Method range of object _global failed

I used this kind of code a lot few days ago and I don't get why it's not working anymore

Comment: Can you write `MsgBox tbl.Name` on the line before the error?

Comment: I add a watch: "Sal_Vol_Ret_Mec"

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the `DataBodyRange` of each `tbl`?

Comment: @vib500 - how exactly your table looks like? Probably it would be quite helpful to provide a screenshot, or simply try from scratch. `Set Rng = Range(tbl.name)` works quite ok for me. Or try `Set Rng = Range(tbl.DataBodyRange.Address)` as proposed by @BigBen.

Comment: @Vityata - no need to use `Range` or `Address` - just `For each c in tbl.DataBodyRange`.

Comment: I put Set Rng = tbl.DataBodyRange and it worked like a charm.
I just understood: in very few tables, I have only one column, but the range of only one column was not OK..IDK. Whatever, it's working :). thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use already existing object components of a `ListObject` - in your case [ListObject.DataBodyRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobject-databodyrange-property-excel) - instead of `Set Rng = Range(tbl.Name)`.

```
For Each tbl In Worksheets("Assumptions").ListObjects
    For each c in tbl.DataBodyRange
    ...
    Next c
Next tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that the parent (The Worksheet) of `.Range()` is not defined explicitly. Thus, it looks for the Table on the `ActiveSheet` or on the Sheet, where the code is. Thus, it was working yesterday, probably before the `ActiveSheet` was different.

As a rule of a thumb in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) - make sure that you always declare the Worksheet of a `Range`, `Cell`, `Column`, `Row` or any other `Range` object. In this case:

```
For Each tbl In Worksheets("Assumptions").ListObjects
        Set Rng = Worksheets("Assumptions").Range(tbl.name)
        For Each c In Rng
            If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
                Worksheets(brand).Range(c.Address).Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next
Next tbl
```

or if you like this one:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets(tbl.Parent.Name).Range(tbl.Name)
```

and if you are working with multiple Excel files, something like this is possible 
(but probably not advisable):

```
Set Rng = Workbooks(tbl.Parent.Parent.Name).Worksheets(tbl.Parent.Name).Range(tbl.Name)
```